Verifying answers for Bayesian probability problem
This is a continuation of Finding prior when there is a previous prior, except that here I want some help on whether I've done part (b) and (c) correctly.
For reference, the problem is as follows:

1. [14 marks] In a legal dispute over paternity, Adam is the alleged father. 
The judge is a Bayesian statistician, and announces at the start that, in the interests of fairness, his prior 
belief is that there is a $50\%$ chance Adam is the father. 
On the first day of the trial, testimonials are given. 
On the second day, it is revealed that the child has blood type B, and according to geneticists, this would 
happen with probability $50\%$ if Adam is the father. Furthermore, based on incidence rates of B genes in 
the population, there is a $10\%$ chance that this child would have blood type B if Adam is not the father. 
At the end of the second day, the judge announces that his assessment of the probability that Adam is the 
father is $75\%$.  
a) [5 marks] What were the judge’s beliefs at the end of the first day?
b) [4 marks] Deduce the ratio of the Judge’s assessment of the likelihood of the testimonials given
that Adam is the father vs given Adam is not the father. [i.e. calculate P(testimonials | Adam is
father) / P(testimonials | Adam is not father) ]
c) [5 marks] There is some dispute over the geneticist’s assessment that “there is a $10\%$ chance the
child would have blood type B if Adam is not the father”. Experts are divided in opinion, with
estimates for this figure ranging uniformly between 10% and 20%. If the Judge summarises this
uncertainty by assigning a Uniform(0.1,0.2) distribution for this figure, rather than using the $10\%$
figure, derive the Judge’s final assessment in this case. [i.e. calculate Prob(Adam is the father | all
evidence) by marginalising over this disputed figure.]

My attempt for parts (b) and (c) are as follows:

From part (a), I got $\frac{3}{8}$ as the answer. Then is the answer just $$\frac{P(T|A)}{P(T|A')} = \frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{5}{8}} = \frac{3}{5}$$

I could have gotten this one wrong, because just like part (a), I found it hard to understand what the problem was saying (in particular, what P(testimonials) is supposed to mean). Again, I did not use the fact that his beliefs before the start of the trial is $50\%$ at all.

For part (c), I continued from part (a), but instead of $0.1$, I put $y$. Then my equation looks like this:

$$
\frac{3}{4} = \frac{0.5x}{0.5x + y(1 - x)}
$$
I put $x$ in terms of $y$:
$$
x = \frac{6y}{6y + 1}
$$
and tried to find the mean (as $y$ is uniform from 0.1 to 0.2), giving me about $0.47$ as the result:
$$
\frac{1}{0.2-0.1} \int_{0.1}^{0.2} \frac{6y}{6y + 1} dy \approx 0.469
$$
Is this correct?

Here is my working for part c)
$P_2(A|C) = \frac{P_2(C|A)P_2(A)}{P_2(C)}$,
where a subscript refers to the day. I.e. $P_2(A|C)$ is the probability that the Judge thinks Adam is the father, on day 2, after receiving all evidence '$C$' from day 2.
$P_2(A)$ is the probability that the Judge gives to Adam being the father at the start of day 2 (aka at the end of day 1), and is the answer that we got for part a), i.e. $P_2(A)=\frac{3}{8}$.
$P_2(C|A)$ is the probability that the child has blood type B given that Adam is the father, and is therefore still 0.5.
Define 'NA' to mean that Adam is not the father, therefore $P_2(A)+P_2(NA)=1$ giving $P_2(NA) = \frac{5}{8}$
Through the law of total probability $P_2(C) = P_2(C|A)P_2(A) + P_2(C|NA)P_2(NA)$
$P_2(C|A)$ is 0.5, and $P_2(C|NA)$ is our uniform distribution, which I will call $y$.
Putting all this together gives,
$P_2(A|C) = \frac{1}{0.2-0.1}\int_{0.1}^{0.2}\frac{0.5 \frac{3}{8}}{0.5\frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{8}y}dy = 0.669$ (using Mathematica).
Therefore the Judge gives the probability that Adam is the father of approximately 67%.

I agree with your part b). Here is my reasoning.
We know that at the end of the first day $P(A|testimonials) = \frac{3}{8}$. Therefore, $P(Not A | testimonials) = \frac{5}{8}$.
Using Bayes theorem for both cases (adam is father given the testimonials, and adam is not the father given the testimonials), we can rearrange for
$\frac{P(testimonials | A)}{ P(testimonials | not A)} = \frac{\frac{P(A|testimonials)*P(testimonials)}{P(A)} }{ \frac{P(not A|testimonials)*P(testimonials)}{P(not A)}}$
The judges prior is that $P(A) = 0.5$, therefore $P(not A) = 0.5$.
We do not need to consider $P(testimonials)$ since the fraction takes care of that.
This therefore simplifies down to:
$P(testimonials | A) / P(testimonials | not A) = \frac{P(A|testimonials)}{P(not A|testimonials)} = \frac{3}{5}$.
I have not completed part c) yet but will update you when I do.

For part c) I believe that you have misunderstood the question. You are using the same method as for part a) which asks what the judge thought at the end of day 1, but we are asked about what he thinks at the end of day 2 (given this new range of probabilities for the child having blood type B if Adam is not the father). In your working you have assumed that what the judge thinks at the end of day 2 is that Adam is the father with p=3/4, and then worked backwards to find what he thinks at the end of day 1. I think you need to do the opposite, taking the prior as the answer from part a).

"what the judge thinks at the end of day 2 is that Adam is the father with p=3/4," - isn't that true? What do you mean by p?

Yes, that is true, but we use that to calculate the answer for part a). In part c), are we not asked to update the probability the judge assigns to Adam being the father, given this updated information about the blood type? I am confused why you are using 3/4 in your working out for this problem - perhaps I am misunderstanding something. What do the left and right sides of your first equation in the working out for part c) represent?

I see my blunder - thanks for catching it. Indeed, I mixed up the "end of day 1" and "end of day 2" parts.
